# Integration test fails as the rendering content does not match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, integration-testing

When I log into my ruby applicaiton, the first page url is http://localhost:3000/tree_display/list. So , when I run the test to assert the same, I am getting this error.

```
[user1 project]$  rake test
DEPRECATION WARNING: String based terminators are deprecated, please use a lambda. (called from included at /home/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/bundler/gems/authlogic-09163c7d2a9b/lib/authlogic/session/callbacks.rb:66)
DEPRECATION WARNING: String based terminators are deprecated, please use a lambda. (called from included at /home/.gem/ruby/2.1.3/bundler/gems/authlogic-09163c7d2a9b/lib/authlogic/session/callbacks.rb:67)
Started

 FAIL["test_login_and_access_bookmarks/managing_bookmarks", BookmarksTest, 0.678676891]
 test_login_and_access_bookmarks/managing_bookmarks#BookmarksTest (0.68s)
        expecting <"tree_display/list"> but rendering with <["content_pages/view", "shared/_header", "shared/_navigation", "auth/_login", "shared/_flash_messages", "shared/_footer_message", "layouts/application"]>
        test/integration/bookmarks_test.rb:15:in `block in <class:BookmarksTest>'

  1/1: [=========================================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:00, Time: 00:00:00

Finished in 0.68149s
1 tests, 2 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
[user1 project]$
```

It is rendering with `<["content_pages/view", "shared/_header", "shared/_navigation", "auth/_login", "shared/_flash_messages", "shared/_footer_message", "layouts/application"]>`. These are supposed to be on the first page when I enter the username and password and then I go to `http://localhost:3000/tree_display/list`

I noticed that the session variable contains this :`@host="www.example.com",`
What is the problem here? Why is it not rendering the tree_display/list? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably login failed in your test or it is taking time to login while you are asserting on previous page in the test. Try adding delays in assertion and login step.